# Unrestricted Gomoku on a small board

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

In [the m,n,k game page from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M,n,k-game), it says that a (6, 6, 5) is proved to be a draw, and (15, 15, 5) is proved to be a win ( I briefly read the paper and it is a rather complicated computer method which has no implementation available online). But there is no information or result for (n, n, 5) where n is between 6 and 15 on that page, I also searched the internet but did not find more relevant results. From my own playing experiences and computer simulation results, games like (7, 7, 5) and (8, 8, 5) are very likely to be a draw. Is there any paper/results for these games? When is the split point of n such that Black is possible to win? Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: This is probably because a win is easier to prove than a draw (because a winning strategy ends the game early whereas a drawing strategy only "wins" at the end of the game). Bigger boards make a win more likely but make proving a draw more difficult. That someone was able to prove a win for $(15,15,5)$ but not for $(14,14,5)$ makes it seem likely that $(n,n,5)$ with $n\lt15$ is a draw but computer resources don't suffice to prove this for $n\gt6$.

Comment: [This thesis](http://www.csie.ntnu.edu.tw/~linss/Students_Thesis/2009_06_29_Liu_Yun_Ching.pdf) from 2009 says that at the time the boundary between win and draw for $5$-in-a-row games was still an open question.